# Php move_uploaded_file server error

Tags: php, web, server, cpanel

I am making a site that allows one user (the admin and owner of the site) to upload his own photos to a gallery on the site. The photo uploads fine and everything, but when I try to move it to the directory, I get an error. I've tried lots of things, even allowing all permissions on the cpanel on ecowebhosting.co.uk. But my script should be able to upload there anyway without group permissions. Here is my php script:

```
$target_dir = "/assets/collages/";
$target_file = $target_dir.basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "assets/collages/";

if (is_dir($upload_dir)) {
    // do upload logic here
} else {
    echo 'Upload directory is not writable, or does not exist.';
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.<br>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.<br>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.<br>";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my form (using bootstrap):

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="year">Year</label>
                <input type="text" name="year" id="year" placeholder="Year" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image File</label>
        <input name="image" type="file" id="image">
        <p class="help-block">Chose the collage image you would like to add.</p>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And lastly, it is on a hosting package, so I don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: And what error do you get? Check if you have access to your web server logs (maybe from the provider control panel).

Comment: @MarcCompte xxxxxxxxx.com xx.xxx.xx.x - - [07/Jun/2016:22:41:12 +0100] "GET http://xxxxxxxxx.com/ftpriurNj.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 169 "-" "JustAnInstaller/0.1" This is all that's in my logs.

Comment: That's an entry about a GET call to a CGI file. There has to be something about a POST call to your php file.

Comment: I found the error! There was nothing in my logs because there was no server error. The error was that I had an extra "/" in front my my directory. So instead of "/assets/collages/" it was "assets/collages/". Rookie mistake. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong parameter:

```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["name"], $target_file)) {
                                             ^^^^
```

You want `tmp_name`. `Name` is the filename as provided by the client, but that's only informational. The actual filename of wherever the server has stored the file temporarily is held in `tmp_name`. Therefore you're trying to move a file which doesn't exist on the server.

And note that you're just assuming the upload succeeded. While you are properly checking if the file is really an image, you really should be checking `$_FILES['image']['error']` FIRST. There's plenty of ways for an upload to fail halfway through, yet still pass getimagesize - that function only looks at the first k-byte or so of the file to get the image magicnumbers/headers information.

Comment: Oh wow. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks. I fixed that, however, it didn't fix the issue. It' s still saying that it couldn't upload. My permissions on the folder in the file manager on cpanel allows reading writing and execution for the owner, but do I need to allow writing for the group? I don't believe I understand that concept entirely. But if I'm getting errors still, I think it has to be permissions possibly. As per the image checking, I don't necessarily need it at this stage because as a tester, I know the files I'm uploading are images. But I will add that later. I appreciate ya.

Comment: Also, my server logs (where I would assume I would find errors) are empty.

Comment: you're running this under a webserver, so all of the file operations will be performed as the webserver userid. therefore whatever permissions you do set need to allow THAT user to do the necessary stuff.

Comment: Is that when I use chmod? And if so, where and how? Thanks for the help.